# Use custom image for button in Ribbon Bar Excel

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2013

I have a few custom functions that I'd like to add to my custom tab and group in the ribbon bar.  I'd like to use a custom image I created and took a snapshot of (.png).  I've seen a few websites that explain how to do so, such as [this one](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2013/09/25/customize-excel-user-interface/#ribbon),[this one](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/684749-add-custom-png-image-excel-ribbon.html), and [this one](http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s2/win009.htm); however, this is way over my head and I'm not even sure where to put the code to insert the file.  Can anyone help me understand this better?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: The guides you linked to seem pretty straightforward: I'm not sure this is a place to ask for someone to re-write them...

Comment: The Ribbon Editor add-in is one of the easiest ways to add Ribbon functionality to a custom add-in.  http://www.andypope.info/vba/ribboneditor.htm

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the thing that I was looking for was an XML editor.  I found more specific instructions on an Excel Add-in website.  Thanks anyways.